# LaunchSreen Image not Showing Properly ios

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

I'm setting a simple image with some constraints on width and height and be centered in parent view in LaunchScreen.Storyboard and its showing it properly and the right position but when I run the Project seem like the image is Squeezed , any Idea on what may cause the problem ?
[image]

Comment: image view's image should be: aspect fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would happen when the personal hotspot is on ( or other such things that add height to status bar ) and the status bar become 20px more longer , fixing that will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content mode of the UIImageView inside the Attribute Inspector to "Aspect Fit" or "Aspect Fill"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this image is small then you should place it in center and add constraints:-

1:- center Horizontal
2:- center vertical
3:- make its height width aspect ratio or fix 
4:- do not attach its left, right, top, bottom constraints

Comment: Read my question, i have already added these not hardcoding right , left ... however this is related to posotion( which is correct here ) and not the imagebeing squeezed